UpgradeParentVersion recipe also delete version of other dependencies in pom.xml
I am trying to execute below recipe to update my parent jar version of one of my target project. mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:dryRun -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=com.hello.myproject:myproject-migration:5.0.30 -Drewrite.activeRecipes=com.test.skernel.migrate-to-6.0.6-set0
But it also deletes version of other dependencies which are even not part of this parent jar.

# change the version of skernel-starter-parent from 5.1.27 to 6.0.6
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.test.skernel.migrate-to-6.0.6-set0
displayName: Change version of skernel-starter-parent
description: Changes the version of skernel-starter-parent from 5.1.27 to 6.0.6
recipeList:     
  - org.openrewrite.maven.UpgradeParentVersion:
      groupId: com.test.skernel
      artifactId: skernel-starter-parent
      newVersion: 6.0.6

Result:-
<parent>
        <groupId>com.test.skernel</groupId>
        <artifactId>skernel-starter-parent</artifactId>
-       <version>5.1.29-SNAPSHOT</version>
+       <version>6.0.6</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test.skernel.samples</groupId>
@@ -48,7 +48,6 @@
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
-           <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

<version>2.7.1</version> deleting is not expected because it not part of parent jar.

When you change a parent pom.xml, we try to also make the idiomatic changes that go along with it; such as removing explicit versions where the parent manages that version, or a newer version. This prevents projects from getting stuck pinned to older incompatible versions, where a newer might be necessary. All part of doing the best we can to migrate your project.
So the change is very much intentional, and we do not offer a way to override that behavior. It might be unexpected, but it should help rather than hurt the overall maintainability of your project.
